# anionic surfactants as salt water induced rust inhibitors

Tags: everyday-chemistry

There are a multitude of product that purport to protect boat engines from the adverse effects of salt water.  These anionic surfactants claim to rinse away salt buildup.  I do not understand how a surfactant would improve water's ability to dissolve NaCl.

Comment: A surfactant won't improve water's ability to dissolve NaCl. Its ability to protect your engine (which might or might not be true) stems from other sources.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a fake, but where do you apply these products? Wouldnt they be washed away instantly with the stream of cooling water?